# A question about independent events

Tags: probability, measure-theory

While studying probability, the following question arose:

> Let $H$ be an event and let $\mathcal{H}=\lbrace H_\lambda|\lambda\in\Lambda\rbrace$ be a family of events in probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$, such that for every $\lambda\in\Lambda$ the following holds: $P(H_\lambda\cap H) = P(H_\lambda)P(H)$, i.e. the events $H_\lambda$ and $H$ are independent. Let $\mathcal{G}=\sigma(\mathcal{H})$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{H}$. Let $G\in\mathcal{G}$ be any event. Are $G$ and $H$ necessarily independent i.e. does it follow that $P(G\cap H) = P(G)P(H)$?

This would be quite a useful lemma, I think. I had an idea for a proof, but the last step didn't quite work as expected. The argument went like this:

We shall write $\mathcal{G}$ as a union of an increasing sequence of more simple sets. Let $\mathcal{B}_0 = \mathcal{H}$. For every successor ordinal $\alpha+1$ define $\mathcal{A}_{\alpha+1} = \lbrace\bigcup\mathcal{J}|\mathcal{J}\subseteq\mathcal{B}_\alpha,\mathrm{card}(\mathcal{J})\leq\aleph_0\rbrace$, the set of all countable unions of the previous sets, and $\mathcal{B}_{\alpha+1}=\lbrace A|\Omega - A\in\mathcal{A}_{\alpha+1} \lor A\in\mathcal{A}_{\alpha+1}\rbrace$, the same with their complements added. For limit ordinals we define $\mathcal{B}_\beta=\bigcup_{\alpha<\beta}\mathcal{B}_\alpha$. Finally define $\mathcal{B} = \bigcup_{\alpha<\omega_1}\mathcal{B}_\alpha$. I guess such an union should make sense, since at each step we stay inside $\mathcal{G}$ ...

Next we prove that $\mathcal{B}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and since every set in the construction of this $\sigma$-algebra is a subset of $\mathcal{G}$, we must have that $\mathcal{B} = \mathcal{G}$.

The only tricky part in proving $\mathcal{B}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra is closure under countable unions. Let $(A_n)_n$ be a sequence of events in $\mathcal{B}$. Then for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there is an ordinal $\alpha_n$ such that $A_n\in\mathcal{B}_{\alpha_n}$. Then there must be some ordinal $\gamma < \omega_1$ such that $\forall n:\alpha_n \leq \gamma$. (Since otherwise $\omega_1$ would be a countable union of countably many sets which it can't be, since it isn't countable. (Assuming the axiom of choice.)) So these events are all elements of $\mathcal{B}_\gamma$ which implies their countable union must lie in $\mathcal{A}_{\gamma+1}\subseteq\mathcal{B}_{\gamma+1}$ and therefore in $\mathcal{B}$.

I was hoping the rest would follow by transfinite induction: if $A\in\mathcal{B}_{\alpha+1}$ then either $A\in\mathcal{A}_{\alpha+1}$ or $\Omega-A\in\mathcal{A}_{\alpha+1}$. The second case would follow from the first case using complements. But the first case is problematic: $P(A\cap H) = P((\bigcup_{E\in\mathcal{J}}E)\cap H) = P((\bigcup_{\tilde{E}\in\mathcal{J}_0}\tilde{E})\cap H) = \sum_{\tilde{E}\in\mathcal{J}_0}P(\tilde{E}\cap H)$. Here $\mathcal{J}\subseteq\mathcal{B}_\alpha$ exists by definition of $\mathcal{A}_{\alpha+1}$ and $\mathcal{J_0}$ is a set of mutually exclusive events giving the same union. The problem is that such a set $\mathcal{J_0}$ can in this case only be proven to lie under $\mathcal{B}_{\alpha+1}$, so we cannot write $P(\tilde{E}\cap H) = P(\tilde{E})P(H)$.

So the proof sadly fails at this last step.

> Is this proof salvageable? (Perhaps by taking relative complements instead in the definition of $\mathcal{B}_{\alpha+1}$ or something like that?) Does such a lemma even hold or do we have to modify it? Are such proofs by transfinite induction useful in probability?

It seems to me probabilists implicitly use lemmas like this all the time, so I am also wondering if such a lemma or a similar one would in fact be useful.

[Comment: The definition of $\mathcal{B}$ above originally used $\mathbf{On}$ which was a slight overkill, so I changed it to $\omega_1$, following the kind suggestion of Asaf Karagila.]

**Added:** In a comment below Dilip Sarwate suggests the following variation on the problem:

> Let $H$ be an event and let $\mathcal{H}=\lbrace H_\lambda|\lambda\in\Lambda\rbrace$ be a family of events in probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$, such that the family of events $\mathcal{H}\cup\lbrace H\rbrace$ is independent i.e. for every finite $\mathcal{S}\subseteq\mathcal{H}\cup\lbrace H\rbrace$ we have $P(\bigcap_{E\in\mathcal{S}}E) = \Pi_{E\in\mathcal{S}}P(E) $, where $\Pi$ denotes the product of the probabilities, as usual. Let $\mathcal{G}=\sigma(\mathcal{H})$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{H}$. Let $G\in\mathcal{G}$ be any event. Are $G$ and $H$ necessarily independent i.e. does it follow that $P(G\cap H) = P(G)P(H)$?

This case actually interests me even more than the "original question" above, since it is this case that I actually needed. (I thought somehow that I can get more out of it by relaxing the conditions to what the question above says. Silly me.)

Comment: Your proof going with induction feels to me like when I'm trying to make things work my way even though my way's the wrong way to go. But it's just a comment. Your intuition is good though ; a set of independent events from $H$ should probably (I'm using *probably* in the common non-mathematical sense here, I'm not convinced though) generate events independent from $H$.

Comment: Yes, that might be true. But part of my question is: what is the right way to go?

Comment: I have no idea, I was just making a comment.

Comment: I think the difficulty here is that the $\sigma$-algebra contains intersections, e.g. events $H_{\lambda}\cap H_{\lambda^\prime}$ and while it is true that $P(H_{\lambda}\cap H) = P(H_{\lambda})P(H)$ and $P(H_{\lambda^\prime}\cap H) = P(H_{\lambda^\prime})P(H)$, why should that imply that $P((H_{\lambda}\cap H_{\lambda^\prime})\cap H) = P(H_{\lambda}\cap H_{\lambda^\prime})P(H)$? @PatrickDaSilva's comment is applicable if _all_ the events in $\mathcal H$ together with $H$ constitute a set of _mutually independent_ events; pairwise independence of events in $\mathcal H$ with $H$ is not enough.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would take a union over *all* the ordinals... the first $\omega_1$ should be enough if you want to talk about a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: You may also want to read [this answer of mine](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/54179/622)

Comment: @Asaf: Thanks, that was also a thing I was wondering about. Right! The reason is that a countable union of countable sets is countable, isn't it?

Comment: @Dejan: Assuming the axiom of choice, yes. Assuming that you are assuming it, yes. :-)

Comment: @Asaf: Yeah, I believe I did assume it all over my failed proof above. I believe I've heard that $\sigma$-algebras without the axiom of choice can be pretty strange. So an interesting question would also be how much of this lemma (adding the assumption Byron Schmuland suggested about $\mathcal{H}$ being a $\pi$-system of course) is provable in $ZF$. Do you know of any such lemmas, maybe? =)

Comment: To be fair, I am not even sure what is the lemma. Probability, and in general measures, has little volume to them without at least the principle of dependent choice. This principle already implies that $\omega_1$ is not the countable union of countable sets, and is enough to develop most of the theory I can think of about probability; and much of the one I know about measures in general.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: One last question is that I'm not really sure about why [set-theory] and [elementary-set-theory] are here. This seems verging on both and neither of those.

Comment: @Dilip: Right! I think this extra condition may actually salvage my proof, after I take the $\mathcal{B}_{\alpha+1}$ to consist of relative complements, that is events of the form $A-B$ where $A,B\in\mathcal{A}_{\alpha+1}$, since then I get $P(\tilde{E}\cap (\Omega - B)\cap H)$ instead of $P(\tilde{E}\cap H)$. I have to think the details through though, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Asaf: That was actually because I was wondering if the thing using $\mathbf{On}$-indexed union made sense and if it can be replaced, which you promptly answered and for which I am very much thankful. So I also wasn't really sure whether the tags were appropriate. I did try to write them down in the order of their importance, however.

Comment: I guess that you can edit that part, and remove both tags. In your defense (perhaps) the order you write them is not the order in which they appear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at Lemma 3.6 (page 50) of *Foundations of modern probability (2nd edition)*
 by Olav Kallenberg. Using the Monotone Class Theorem, 
he shows that the result is true provided $\cal H$ is a $\pi$-system, that is, 
closed under intersections.

However the result is false in general. Take Robert Israel's example from 
the question [Independence of sigma algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76123/independence-of-sigma-algebra).
That is, let $X_2,X_3$ be independent r.v.s  taking the values 
$\pm 1$ with probability $1/2$ each, and define $X_1=X_2X_3$.

The event $X_1=1$ is independent of $X_2=1$ and independent of $X_3=1$, 
but not of the intersection $(X_2=1)\cap (X_3=1)$.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I'll check it out. These $\pi$-systems look like a very useful thing to know.

Comment: The Monotone Class Theorem is a wonderful tool that often allows us to avoid families indexed on ordinals and transfinite induction, etc. In general, Kallenberg's book is a great source on many topics in probability. I'm a big fan!

Comment: So does this mean that the Monotone Class Theorem and Transfinite Induction are mostly interchangeble when it comes to doing probability? Or are there known contexts where one of them might be very useful but the other not so much?

Comment: I've thought this through, and the lemma you suggest works magnificently. It solves the relevant variation (suggested by Dilip Sarwate) on the problem I added in three lines: if we define $\mathcal{K}_1$ to be the set of all finite intersections of elements in $\mathcal{H}$ and $\mathcal{K}_2 = \lbrace H\rbrace$, it is trivial to check that these two are independent $\pi$-systems, which solves the problem immediately. Thanks again for suggesting this illuminating book.